# AjaxCall delete not working receive 405 error webAPI

Tags: asp.net, web-config, webapi

I've tried to change the WEB CONFIG to the following per older questions  but it's still now working. -

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="WebDAV"/>
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
        <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
        <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler"/>
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
          preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
    </handlers>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Any suggestions?
Thank in advance

Comment: This is javascript and html? Please update tags.

Comment: My client side is in java script and html.